# Inserting Dynamic Data and Request Chaining Runscope

Tags: json, api, runscope

When the first step return a json object like this

```
  {
"success":true,
"total":21,
"items":
[
{"id":"762"},
{"id":"763"},
{"id":"764"}
]
}
```

how can i assign variable id to the first "id" item in response

i have done it like this but it didn't work

[image]

i also tried `items.id`, `items[0].id` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign a variable to an item in a list, you can use a [post-response script](https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/scripts/post-response).

In this case, something like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
var myId = data.items[0].id;
variables.set("id", myId);
```

Comment: items[0].id in the UI should also work but scripts are always a safe work around.